# PayPal Checkout: Cannot make USD payments within India

Tags: paypal

I have website with a PayPal merchant account in India.

If a user from my website tries to make a 1 USD payment through their PayPal account, it shows the error message "We’re sorry. This seller doesn’t accept payments in your currency. Please return to the seller and choose another way to pay."

If they pay via the Debit or Credit Card option, it says Things don't appear to be working right now.

However, I have both USD and INR currency support in my merchant account.

Can anyone tell me a solution to pay with USD currency from within India?
how can we handle this . can we handle both international and local payment in paypal ? is there any automatic currency detect available based on country ?

do any other payment gateway easier to handle both local and international currencies ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution. For regulatory reasons, intraborder payments within India are only permitted to be in INR.

This is not a technical issue.

Comment: how can we handle this . can we handle both international and local payment in paypal ?
is there any automatic currency detect available based on country ?

Comment: There is nothing automatic about it. You must detect or have the user select their location, use this information to present prices in a currency appropriate for the buyers location, and at checkout time set up the transaction using that currency:  INR for India buyers, and something else for buyers outside India.

Comment: ok this could be helpful for me.. do any other payment gateway easier to handle both local and international currencies ?